# WordPress Showing IP Address Instead of Domain

Tags: virtual-hosts

When I navigate to my WordPress site, I get the IP address instead of the domain name. In settings> general I have changed the domain name but then I get an error message that the site cannot be found. I have also done this in the database itself and I have adjusted the vhost files yet I get an IP address. I suspect it is due to one of the wordpress files but I have no idea which file? If I place a index file with hello world in the htdocs folder, it works and I get a domain name instead of an ip address...

OS: Ubuntu Server
Web Server: Apache2

Comment: Did you change to Domain name in options table at 2 places? Site Url and Home Url?

Comment: Yes I have changed both urls

Comment: It could be DNS cache. You can try on different browser or with different internet source, like cellular data.

Comment: I tried that too, but unfortunately that doesn't work either :/

Comment: try DNS tools online, like https://dnschecker.org/, to ensure domain has propagated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my situation it was a problem with the firewall on the vhost. Otherwise, try to replace the htaccess...

But i have still the issue, that the ip address is still set in the admin backend, for ex. when i hover over the "next page arrow" on the create pages admin site

Comment: What do you mean by firewall on the vhost? I have given the .htacces file a different name and this has not helped.